# Lightbox2 works on all browsers except FireFox

Tags: firefox, lightbox2

I have went through numerous posts about this and still can't get an answer. I created this website:

www.poochiemoo.com

and they work on all browsers except Firefox, when going to any of the galleries and attempting to look at the images.

One strange thing I learned, was that when viewing this offline it worked fine. But when moving them over to the host servers, they all stopped working. After some investigating, I learned that it had to do with the host Linux servers and how I name things using upper and lower case. Most of the problems were solved, but this lightbox one seems to be getting the best of me.

Answer (score 2):

Your images are 404ing. It looks like the image `href`s are all using backslashes. Chrome and IE are automatically fixing the error, but Firefox isn't.

Your links are in the format:

```
Images\Cupcakes\artistpalette.JPG
```

Change them to the format:

```
Images/Cupcakes/artistpalette.JPG
```

At the moment the backslashes are being encoded by Firefox, so links like this are generating a 404:

```
http://www.poochiemoo.com/Images%5CCupcakes%5Cartistpalette.JPG
```